# /fill area of command blocks with commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm making this adventure map, and kinda got tired of placing NBT command blocks one by one.

Is there a way to fill an area with command blocks that already have a command in them?

The closest i got was just filling an area with command blocks, then manually putting the command on each one of them. But honestly that was too tiresome.

```
/fill ~ ~-1 ~ ~15 ~-1 ~15 minecraft:command_block
```

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fill them with the same command, like so:

`/fill ~ ~-1 ~ ~15 ~-1 ~15 minecraft:command_block 0 replace {Command:"/hey"}`